# Solving for $\beta$ in $\tan\gamma = C \tan\beta$, $0 \leq C \leq 1$, where $\beta$ must be in same quadrant as $\gamma$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I am pretty weak with *Mathematica*, so please, nothing overly complicated. The `ArcTan[x, y]` function allows for a full range of $2 \pi$ in the output. However, for the equation $\beta = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan\gamma}{C} \right)$, $C$ is always positive, so I only get $\pi$ range in $\beta$. But I NEED $\beta$ to be in the same quadrant as $\gamma$. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 3):

Split the tangent:

```
ArcTan[c Cos[γ], Sin[γ]]
```

A quick `Manipulate[]` for fun:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{{Opacity[1/2, ColorData[97, 1]], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, γ}]},
                     {Opacity[1/2, ColorData[97, 2]],
                      Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, ArcTan[c Cos[γ], Sin[γ]]}]}}, PlotRange -> 1],
           {{c, 1/2}, 0, 1}, {{γ, π/4}, -π, π}]
```

Comment: GENIUS! You are a prodigy.

Comment: I believe I'm too old to qualify, but thank you. :)